# Can I create my own warp connection?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-2

Playing as Sol Force one of my systems went supernova. Besides costing the lives of a billion of my citizens, which by itself was already pretty inconvenient, there are now no active node connections between two two halves of my empire.

[image: broken connection]

Is there a way to create my own connection between the two halves of the empire?